# C++ Classes - Pointers question

Tags: c++, pointers, class, compiler-construction

I had a quiz at school and there was this question that I wasn't sure if I answered correctly. I could not find the answer in the book so I just wanted to ask you.

```
Point* array[10];
```

How many instances of class Point are created when the above code is called?

I answered none because it only creates space for 10 instances, but doesn't create any. Then my friend said it was just one because when the compiler sees Point* it just creates one instance as a base.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It creates no `Point`s.

What it does is creates an array of ten pointers that can point to `Point` objects (it doesn't create space for ten *instances*).  The pointers in the array are uninitialized, though, and no `Point` objects are actually created.

Comment: thanks.... i knew i was wrong about allocating the space. the question just asked how many, but my dumb ass had to give an explanation when i didn't need it.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost correct.

The code creates no instances of `Point`.  It does create 10 instances of `Point *`, though.  It does *not* create the *space* for the `Point` instances; that is done using a call to `new`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`Point* array[10]` creates an array with ten slots for pointers, numbered 0..9.

You are both wrong - no initialisation takes place in C++ with such a statement, unless

1. you are running a special memory allocator which zeros memory, such as SmartHeap (or C++/CLI) or
2. if the array is outside of a function (eg: just within a .cpp file as global), in which case all the pointers are zeroed.

Absolutely no instances are created.

Respectfully disagreeing with strager's point, there is no such thing as an *instance* of Point* and it would be dangerous to think of such a thing existing. There is only space for a pointer and compile-time checking to ensure you can only assign a pointer of that type, or pointer to a subclass, into that pointer.

Comment: What about instances of `Point *`?

Comment: I argue that `std::vector<char>`, `MyStruct`, `Point *`, `float`, and `int` can all be instantiated.

Comment: Question on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745487/what-can-be-instantiated

Comment: Judging by your response on that issue and the bit quoted, the standard would seem to suggest that the array is a single instance (allocated by new) and the Point* slots within the array are still NOT instances ;-). I'm a POD!=instance kinda guy.

Answer (score 1):

> no initialisation takes place in C++ with such a statement

The `Point*` objects in `array` are zero-initialized if `array` is global.

Comment: But why would anyone have a global array in a non-C environment (and even then globals might be avoided)

Comment: good point. The precise wording (from C++ Programming Language sec 9.4.1) is "nonlocal variables...variables defined outside any function...by default initialised to the default for its type."